# React проект переписать js на typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

Есть готовый проект на React (созданный `npx create-react-app myproject`).
**Подскажите пожалуйста как переписать всё на typescript ?**
Понятно что файлы компонентов я перепишу на синтаксис `ts`, но что конкретно и в какой последовательности надо сделать ?
(изменить тип файла `.js` на ? подключить script компилирующий из `.ts` в `.js` ?)
Заранее благодарю за помощь !

Comment: [вот здесь](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-typescript/) должно быть описано подробно. если не справитесь - обратитесь еще раз сюда

Comment: На примере с webpack. Сначала ставите пакеты `typescript`, `ts-loader` и типов (`@types/react`, `@types/react-dom`, и другие по мере надобности), потом в webpack конфиге указываете свой лоадер для `ts` и `tsx`, добавляете `tsconfig.json`, настраиваете там опции и каталоги, после этого уже меняете расширения с `js` на `ts` и переписываете всё на новый лад. Это если в кратце.

Comment: Ещё лучше - используйте next.js, там всё за вас перекомпилируется.